# Reshaping the Row into Columns of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert the Dataframe columns into rows

```
A   B   C  D  E   F
--------------------
1   a   x  11  k  9
2   b   y  22  j  10
3   c   z  33  h  11
4   d   p  44  g  12
5   e   q  55  f  13
```

in the above sample data frame, I want to convert into

```
B   D   E   1  2  3  4  5   M1  M2   M3   M4  M5
-------------------------------------------------
a  11   k   x   y  z  p  q  9   10   11   12  13
b  12   j   y  z  p  q      9   10   11   12  13
c  13   h   z  p  q         9   10   11   12  13
d  14   g   p  q            9   10   11   12  13
e  15   f   q               9   10   11   12  13
```

Here I do first is convert the **values** of Columns A into Header of the new data frame (i.e  1,2,3,4,5  in new Dataframe). then I arrange the value in column C in value in of header(1,2,3,4,5), then I create a new column in data which are (M1, M2, M3, M4, M5) and populate the Value of Columns F value in each column of new DataFarme.

I try to do using Pivot table then Multi index data frame is created and also Left and right shift I am not able to do .so help me to solve this problem.

[New Data Frame image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOI9K.png)

Comment: thanks,@anky_91  for helping me in question formatting

Comment: [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [more Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) with `fill_value` if pandas 0.24+ first, then create new DataFrame by `F` column and [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
for i, x in enumerate(df.C):
    df[i+1] = df.C.shift(-i, fill_value='')
    #pandas below
    #df[i+1] = df.C.shift(-i).fillna('') 

df1 = pd.DataFrame([df.pop('F').tolist()], 
                    index=df.index, 
                    columns=[f'M{x+1}' for x in range(len(df))])
df = df.drop('C', axis=1).join(df1)
print (df)
   A  B   D  E  1  2  3  4  5  M1  M2  M3  M4  M5
0  1  a  11  k  x  y  z  p  q   9  10  11  12  13
1  2  b  22  j  y  z  p  q      9  10  11  12  13
2  3  c  33  h  z  p  q         9  10  11  12  13
3  4  d  44  g  p  q            9  10  11  12  13
4  5  e  55  f  q               9  10  11  12  13
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't fancy - but i think it works!

```
bde_df = df[['B', 'D', 'E']].copy()

c_df = df['C'].transpose(copy=True)
c_df = c_df.append([c_df]*4, ignore_index=True)
c_df = c_df.apply(lambda x: x.shift(-1, axis=0))

bde_df[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] = c_df[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]

f_df = df['F'].transpose(copy=True)
f_df = f_df.append([f_df]*4, ignore_index=True)
f_df.rename(columns={1: 'M1', 2: 'M2', 3: 'M3', 4: 'M4', 5: 'M5'})
bde_df[['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5']] = f_df[['M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5']]

print(bde_df)
```

Let me know if this helps!